# Do keyframe animations work on span id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a span with an id.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span id="jrm-featured-products" style="font-family: Poiret One; font-size: 36px;">Featured  Products</span></p>
```

And here is my CSS :-

```
 @-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
        transform-origin: left bottom;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
         transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
         transform: rotate(0);
         opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
         -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
         -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
          transform-origin: left bottom;
         -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
         -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
         -ms-transform: rotate(0);
          transform: rotate(0);
         -moz-transform: rotate(0);
          opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    #jrm-featured-products.animate {
         -webkit-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
         -moz-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
          animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
         visibility: visible;
    }

    #jrm-featured-products {
         visibility:  hidden;
    }
```

The animation works but it only fades it. No rotation like it is supposed to. I tried it on a div id and it worked.

**Is my span code correct? or any errors?**

P.S. I'm using the jquery plugin Waypoints so that is why there is a .animate. (it toggles it hence creating the animation when the elemet comes into view) but that isn't too relevant to my problem.

Also, i'll spare you the long story, but I really need it to target the span id rather than the div id.

thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, posted the css for a div class I was targeting to test. All is good now in the post. Sorry!

Comment: So basically the issue is that the animation only fades. It doesn't rotate like it's suppose to according to the code

Answer (score 0):

You have used `.` for `jrm-featuredproducts`. `.` represents class in CSS. `#` represents ID in CSS. So, you just replace `.` to `#`.

```
#jrm-featuredproducts.animate {
-webkit-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
-moz-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
visibility: visible;
}

#jrm-featuredproducts {
visibility:  hidden;
}
```

Comment: opps sorry I posted the wrong css. That was for when I was targetting a custom div class. Ill update in one sec. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate a span element you need to make it act as if it has a position, width, etc. A span by default doesn't, it just takes up the space it's at. You therefore need to add `display: inline-block;` to your spans style/css. In your case I guess that would be:

`#jrm-featured-products.animate {
    -webkit-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
    -moz-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
    animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Also instead of visibility I'm pretty sure you could use `display: inline-block;` only and to hide when not animating you could use `display: none;`.